# Change color of collapsible on click materialize

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I would like to change the color of the collapsible header only when I click on it.

```
<div class="collapsible-header" onclick="connect()"></div>
```

I have to add the color inside the class element, and I do not really know how to add something to it when I call the "connect" funtion. Is this possible ?

Thank you !

Tried with the following but is not working

HTML

```
<div class="collapsible-header" onclick="connect(this)">Robot</div>
```

And in JS

```
function connect(element) 
{ 
    element.style.color = 'red';
    if (connection_status == 0)
    { 
        client.connect(options);
    };
}
```

Comment: Share your code what you had tried yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsbin.com/sojefubudo/edit?html,js,console,output

```
<div class="collapsible-header" onclick="connect(this)"></div>
```

And in javascript :

```
function connect(element) {
  element.style.color = 'red';
}
```

Comment: I was doing something wrong, now it works perfectly thank you !!
Do you have any idea how to change the background color of the collapsible instead of the color of its content ? thanksss

Answer (score 3):

Take a new class and assign the styles you want to append then do this

```
$(".collapsible-header").click(function(){
    $(".collapsible-header").toggleClass("NEWCLASS");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/swarn_singh/9a6djpwp/

```
<div onclick="this.style.color = 'red'">
Change color with inline javascript
</div>

<div onclick="changeColor(this)">
Change color with javascript function
</div>

<script>
    function changeColor(element){
        element.style.color = 'blue';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="collapsible-header" onclick="javascript:this.className += ' additionalClass'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ToggleClass for better result

```js
(function(){
    $("#run").click(()=>{
        //$(this).css('background','yellow');
        $("#run").toggleClass('yellow');
    });
}());
```

```css
.yellow {
    background: yellow!important;
}

.red {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="run" class="red" style="position:absolute;height:100px;width:10px;"></div>
```